# What would be the correct preposition to be placed here? I shall be glad _____ his assistance.

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I've thought of using with/for but I don't think it seems to fit in here. I'd definitely appreciate if somebody could help me out with this one.

Comment: I would use "of". [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glad+for%2Cglad+of%2Cglad+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cglad%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglad%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglad%20with%3B%2Cc0) implies that's most common. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glad) also has an "of" example. You can use these resources to enhance or answer your own questions in future (I think the lack of research in your question is causing close/down votes). Welcome to ELU.

Comment: There is no single "correct" preposition. Of the possible words or phrases that could be put in the blank spot, it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it can be completed with just one word. I suggest 'to be of'.

As in: "I shall be glad ***to be of*** his assistance."